# Unable to remove localStorage data

Tags: javascript, html

This is some weird error:

```
localStorage.removeItem("myKey");
var temp = localStorage.getItem("myKey");

// temp = undefined
```

But, if I ctrl-F5 and do this:

```
var temp = localStorage.getItem("myKey");
console.log(temp);
```

Then all data is still there! How can I completely remove it?

Comment: maybe you are setting it in the page load

Comment: Amit is right. You must have a method to set this key if it's empty.

Comment: Nope, I set the data on a click of a button

Comment: show us the relevant code

Comment: I don't run anything on page load. The data is collected via an ajax call, but it's not run on page load or anything

Comment: The code you've posted should work as expected, the key should be removed, forever, so something else must be going on.

Comment: That's what I thought, as it's undefined after remove it....

Comment: does localStorage.myKey also return a value?

Comment: Also tried this using two different browsers. If I remove the data in one browser, pause execution exactly in debug. Then load the page in the 2nd browser I can access the old data.. Must be a local storage bug??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove all localStorage data, do it with:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/f5w3p/

Now... to remove only specific `Item` and not all the data.. just with `removeItem`

```
localStorage.removeItem('test')
```

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/f5w3p/1/

...
If after  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> you still get some or even same data as before...
...then you must be setting up that data again before you actually read it.

Give us a full working fiddle example and for sure, someone find's out where your problem is.

Comment: Ah, no it worked. Didn't see you only did remove one of the items.

Comment: The power of async call.... It was my code that didn't finish as expected due to it beeing async . My bad, works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
 delete window.localStorage["myKey"]
```

Comment: No difference. After I reload the page, my data is still there

Comment: Provide the complete source!

Comment: Yes, you should provide us the complete source. There must be code to keep creating that key.

Comment: @Joakim M It's too much to dig out

Comment: @Tamura It's not. It's an ajax call that is made after a few clicks, No ajax call is beeing run in console

Comment: @BakedInhalf If there is nothing important in the localstorage, how about trying to clear it all once using this 

    localStorage.clear();

Comment: @Tamura If I clear it at page load, it will be removed. But I don't want that. It is cleared by pressing a button